# Resharper - How to add more linefeeds to the end of a surround template?

Tags: resharper

I am trying to do something quite simple. When resharper surrounds selected code with an if statement it does not all a new line at the end:

Original code:

```
var test = "Hello World";
var test2 = ("Goodbye");
```

Code wrapped:

```
if (true)
{
    var test = "Hello World";

}    var test2 = ("Goodbye");
```

I want it like this:

```
if (true)
{
    var test = "Hello World";

}
var test2 = ("Goodbye");
```

I have edited the if surrpound template to have newlines at the end and have even restarted VS. No luck. Example:

[image]

How do I add a newline after the surround code?
Is there a list somewhere of the tags available for these templates? Perhaps it is a tag that I need?

Comment: Did you select only the 'var test = "Hello World";' string before calling the surrounding template? Since looks like you selected the initial part of the second line as well. Anyway, you can place "$END$" outside the curly braces after inserting any number of new lines - ReSharper will keep them.

Comment: Yes, I select the entire line rather then =just the text. The lf at the end of the line is in the selection.

Comment: Interesting. There seem to be a lot of different templates for "if". There are four different layers of live templates for both live templates and surround templates. I have edited every single template one at a time by adding "Test" to the end. None of the edits seem to end up inserting "test" when I use Ctl-K-S surround. Do I need to restart VS after editing the templates? I am using the Resharper->Tools->Template Explorer to do the editing from.

Comment: Ctrl+K+S has nothing in common with ReSharper. It is mapped to the "Edit.SurroundWith" action which is the Visual Studio action. To find out the right ReSharper shortcut, please open the "ReSharper | Edit" menu and check the shortcut for the "Surround with template" item.

Comment: By the way, you can surround the code without even using a shortcut. Select the line of code | start typing "if" | complete "if" from the ReSharper code completion popup | ReSharper will surround the line with the "if" template